Missing computational symmetries for orbitals in CFour
When carrying out a CFour calculation, a table like the following is printed after convergence of the SCF equations:
  ORBITAL EIGENVALUES (ALPHA)  (1H = 27.2113834 eV)

       MO #        E(hartree)               E(eV)           FULLSYM    COMPSYM
       ----   --------------------   --------------------   -------   ---------
                                        *
                                        *
                                        *

    8    13          -0.7053484644         -19.1935074949    PIu        B2u (2)
    9    18          -0.7053484644         -19.1935074949    PIu        B3u (3)
   10    34          -0.5359129120         -14.5829317180    PIg        B3g (6)
   11    38          -0.5359129120         -14.5829317179    PIg        B2g (7)
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   12    14           0.2109566776           5.7404230354    PIu        B2u (2)
   13    19           0.2109566776           5.7404230354    PIu        B3u (3)
   14     5           0.2490778454           6.7777527482    SGg+        Ag (1)
                                        *
                                        *
                                        *

where I've ommitted some of the lower-lying occupied and higher-lying virtual MOs. Note the table above is for CO2 at equilibrium. All the entries in the COMPSYM are filled out. I have a different D_{inf h} tri-atomic where some of the entries in the COMPSYM column are missing (or "partly-missing", see the lone "g" for MO 57):
  ORBITAL EIGENVALUES (ALPHA)  (1H = 27.2113834 eV)

       MO #        E(hartree)               E(eV)           FULLSYM    COMPSYM
       ----   --------------------   --------------------   -------   ---------
                                        *
                                        *
                                        *
   50    15          -1.0591022049         -28.8196361582    SGg+        Ag (1)
   51    42          -1.0562187839         -28.7411742843    PIu         Ag (2)
   52    64          -1.0562187831         -28.7411742611    PIu        B2u (3)
   53    98          -1.0516873793         -28.6178684956    SG             (5)
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   54    16          -0.4209902988         -11.4557284295    SGg+        Ag (1)
   55    82          -0.4129963172         -11.2382011310    PI             (4)
   56    17          -0.4129963172         -11.2382011308    PI             (1)
   57    99          -0.4030733887         -10.9681845185    PIg          g (5)
                                        *
                                        *
                                        *

Why does this happen?
